# how to destroy the every <li> elements using each()

Tags: jquery

```
<ul>
      <li class="list">Coffee</li>
      <li class="list">Tea</li>
      <li class="list">Milk</li>
    </ul>
```

hi i having a code like above.I need to destroy only the

tags individually using jquery each()

destroy method can be a private funtion.

how to do this?

Comment: need to destroy only li tags individually using $.each()

Comment: why not use `.remove()` ? why need to use `.each()` ? any special reason?

Comment: my requirement is only remove the class name "list" from all li

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d514jgfa/) this is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('li').each(function(){
$(this).remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list">Coffee</li>
  <li class="list">Tea</li>
  <li class="list">Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you want to use $.each only to remove every element then this is not optimized code and it is senseless to use $.each in terms of performance too.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('ul').find('li.list').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list">Coffee</li>
  <li class="">Tea</li>
  <li class="list">Milk</li>
  <li class="list">Coffee</li>
  <li class="">Tea</li>
  <li class="list">Milk</li>
</ul>
```

No need to use `.each()` just select the li you want to remove

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```js
// With each
$('ul li').each(function(index, value){
    if($(value).hasClass('list')) // Or any other filter.
    {
      $(value).remove();
    }
});


// Alternatively without each.
$('ul li.list').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list">Coffee</li>
  <li class="list">Tea</li>
  <li class="list">Milk</li>
  <li class="non-list">Water</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: As @guradio mentioned, there's really no reason why you should use .each. I just figured that there's some other logic behind this that required you to do it in a .each loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("li").each(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
        $(this).remove();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery there is no need to use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each) to remove the `li` individually. 
`$('li')` means that all the `li` available in that `html page`.

You need to use a single line,

```
$('li').remove();
```

```js
$('#first li').remove();

// To delete the li having class list

$('#second .list').remove();

// To delete the li not having class list

$('#third :not(.list)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="first">
    <li class="list">Coffee</li>
    <li class="list">Tea</li>
    <li class="list">Milk</li>
</ul>
<p> To delete the li having class list</p>
<ul id="second">
    <li class="list">Coffee</li>
    <li class="list">Tea</li>
    <li class="list">Milk</li>
    <li>Fruits</li>
 </ul>

<p> To delete the li not having class list</p>
<ul id="third">
    <li class="list">Coffee</li>
    <li class="list">Tea</li>
    <li class="list">Milk</li>
    <li>Fruits</li>
 </ul>
```